# Play Framework - Sql query returning 0 result

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

```
public static List<SqlRow> findQuery(int page , int index, String source , String destination , Date date) {



    String sql = "select DISTINCT airplane.id,airplane.reg_no,airplane.type,airplane.total_seat,source,destination,depart_date,amount from airplane,routee,flight,fare,airport ,flight_airplane   where airplane.id IN  (select AIRPLANE_ID  from FLIGHT_AIRPLANE where FLIGHT_ID IN (select id from flight where depart_date= :date \n" +
            "AND ROUTEE_ID IN (select id from routee where source= :first and destination= :destination and airport_id IN (select id from airport where CITY= :first OR COUNTRY= :first) AND fare_id IN (select id from fare) ))\n" +
            ") and source= :first  and destination= :destination and depart_date= :date order by amount   ;";

    SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("first",source);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("destination",destination);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("date",date);

    return  sqlQuery.findList();

}
```

This is the Query i wrote to connect various table and return a list . This work great in my Computer , but if i try it in different PC/laptop it always return 0 result . Let me know what i am doing wrong .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the binding value (NULL) from the Form and hence NULL value was passing as a parameter which Yield 0 Results . To fix the Binding Value problem all i did was :

**Activator clean**

**Activator compile**

**Activator run**